# Publishing a golang module: Semantic versioning

Tags: go, publish, go-packages

I've been trying to create and publish a golang SDK for my web application: https://datelist.io
Everything works well on my local setup. However, things are started to get more difficult once I'd like to publish my SDK to the https://pkg.go.dev/ website

The code I'd like to publish is available there: github.com/datelist/datelist-sdk-golang

I've read a few tutorials, and, if I understand correctly, all I needed was to:

- Create my public repository
- Add a go.mod file at the root of my repository
- Ask the proxy.golang.org website to index my changes

I've tried different ways to index my changes, and, according to that link:
https://go.dev/about/
Once solution is to visit that page:
https://proxy.golang.org/MYMODULE_PATH

I've thus tried:
https://proxy.golang.org/github.com/datelist/datelist-sdk-golang/@v/v1.0.0.info

However, I've got the following error:
`not found: github.com/datelist/datelist-sdk-golang@v1.0.0: invalid version: unknown revision v1.0.0`

I've tried different things. I've published two tags on my github repository: v1.0.0 and 1.0.0 and it doesn't work. I've checked: my code looks valid, and the version seems to exist, as I can go to: https://proxy.golang.org/github.com/datelist/datelist-sdk-golang/@v/ce18fa0756c2.info
However, I'm stuck when it comes to adding my SDK to go.dev

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your module in its current state is not valid which is why its not visible via the proxy. See below on how to remediate your module issue.

Answer (score 2):

Your [go.mod](https://github.com/Datelist/datelist-sdk-golang/blob/main/go.mod) (latest commit `ce18fa`) module name is incorrect (`/v1.0.0` is not needed):

```
module github.com/datelist/datelist-sdk-golang/v1.0.0
```

the [go.mod](https://github.com/Datelist/datelist-sdk-golang/blob/v1.0.0/go.mod) at git release tag `v1.0.0` points to an import path `datelist.io/sdk` that does not exist:

```
module datelist.io/sdk
```

Update your `go.mod` to this (valid URL - with no tag suffix):

```
module github.com/datelist/datelist-sdk-golang
    
go 1.16
```

and then git tag this committed release as say `v1.0.1` - and that should make your module work.

Consumers of your library can then:

```
go get github.com/datelist/datelist-sdk-golang
```

or explicitly:

```
go get github.com/datelist/datelist-sdk-golang@v1.0.1
```

The former implicitly chooses the latest `semver` version via git tags - `v1.0.1` in this case.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed reply. 
Indeed, it looks like a bad mistake. Now that I fixed it, I get the following error:
```GOPROXY=https://proxy.golang.org GO111MODULE=on go get github.com/datelist/datelist-sdk-golang/@v/v1.0.2-0.20210809041300-f5c4a5594391
go get: package github.com/datelist/datelist-sdk-golang is in the main module, so can't request version v/v1.0.2-0.20210809041300-f5c4a5594391```

Could you help me to understand it?

Comment: [go.mod tagged v1.0.1](https://github.com/Datelist/datelist-sdk-golang/blob/v1.0.1/go.mod) still has the bad suffix. The [latest commit f5c4a5 go.mod](https://github.com/Datelist/datelist-sdk-golang/commit/f5c4a559439199160c5be22c99f59282b902df90) is correct - but not tagged with a semver. You can verify that this works by `GOPROXY=https://proxy.golang.org GO111MODULE=on go get github.com/datelist/datelist-sdk-golang@f5c4a559439199160c5be22c99f59282b902df90`. But obviously its better to get a semver for this release, so tag `f5c4a5...` with a git tag of  say`v1.0.2`.

Comment: FYI: your latest command attempt almost worked, I think you meant: `GOPROXY=https://proxy.golang.org GO111MODULE=on go get github.com/datelist/datelist-sdk-golang@v1.0.2-0.20210809041300-f5c4a5594391` (i.e. no `/@v/`)